# Changing value in all inputs from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I write a simple function using hrome.storage.local.get

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['valueInput'], (result) => {
  if (typeof result.valueInput !== 'undefined') {
    let selectorInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    result.valueInput.forEach((item, index) => selectorInput[index].value = item);
  }
});
```

And i splice this code to independent function

```
function getFromeStorage(value) {
    let arr = [];
    chrome.storage.local.get(value, (result) => {
        if (typeof result.valueInput !== 'undefined') {
            result.valueInput.forEach((item, i) => arr[i] = item);
        }
    });
    return arr;
\\ Array(18)[0: "3" 1: "1" 2: "1" 3: "1" 4: "1" 5: "1" 6: "1" 7: "1" 8: "1" 9: "1" 10: "1" 11: "1" 12: "1" 13: "1" 14: "1" 15: "1" 16: "1" 17: "1"]

}
```

But when i splice this function this function wont work

```
let selectorInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let valueInput = getFromeStorage("valueInput");
valueInput.forEach((item, index) => selectorInput[index].value = item);
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td class="center-align">Administrowanie systemami operacyjnymi</td>
    <td class="center-align row">
    <input type="number" class="input-default-weight" min="1" max="20" value="1">
    <i id="hint-default-weight" class="material-icons md-dark center-vertically tooltipped hint" data-position="top" data-delay="250" data-tooltip="Ilość lekcji w tygodniu" data-tooltip-id="1b1400b4-3270-0b0c-da17-8540ce6f2408">info_outline</i></td>  
    <td class="center-align">5</td>
    <td class="center-align yearPresent">86%</td>
</tr>
```

This is the same code but i only splice my main code to function and i call this in my code. How can i fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're returning the `arr` variable **before** the callback has been called so it's always returning an empty array.

```
function getFromeStorage(value) {
    let arr = [];
    chrome.storage.local.get(value, (result) => {
        // This function won't fill 'arr' until later
        if (typeof result.valueInput !== 'undefined') {
            result.valueInput.forEach((item, i) => arr[i] = item);
        }
    });
    // This empty 'arr' gets returned too early
    return arr;
```

Since `chrome.storage.local.get` is asynchronous your function accessing it must deal with that. One way is to add a callback or Promise to your function. To keep it simple here's how it would look with a callback:

```
function getFromeStorage(value, callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(value, (result) => {
    const arr = [];
    if (typeof result.valueInput !== 'undefined') {
      result.valueInput.forEach((item, i) => arr[i] = item);
    }
    callback(arr);
  });
}
```

You would then have to change how you use the function to wait for the `callback` to be called like this:

```
let selectorInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let valueInput = getFromeStorage("valueInput", (valueInput) =>{
  valueInput.forEach((item, index) => selectorInput[index].value = item);
});
```

Comment: Thx bro for your amazing answer :D

Comment: Instead of populating a new array, you can simplify this by using `callback(result.valueInput || [])`

Comment: @Titus yes, but this question was about understanding the asynchronous behaviour so I wanted to focus on the way callbacks work rather than optimising other aspects of the code.

Comment: I get it, maybe the OP will see my comment and make the change himself.

Comment: Is a way to add this variable to variable outside this function ?

Comment: you can set a variable outside of the function to the value it has, but it will not hold that value until after the callback function has happened. To be sure you have the right value you should put the processing that depends on it within the body of the callback function.

Comment: If you use Promises, then you can so something like this:

`let myVar = await getFromeStorage("valueInput");`
But that is a different topic - Look up Promises to learn more about that